# My WordPress cron job can't find the /bin/bash directory

Tags: wordpress, cron, jobs

I am making a website in WordPress. I disabled the WordPress cron job, and am having my host provider, Bluehost, do my cron. I added the correct info to make the cron, but Bluehost emailed me this:

> Can't exec "/bin/bash": No such file or directory at /usr/sec/bin/setupfake line 354.

shell failed - I have no idea what I did wrong, or how to fix it.

Comment: What's the cron info you entered?

Comment: I'll put 'my website' here, instead if my real website, but I entered: 
wget -q -O - http://my website/wp-content/plugins/woozone/do-cron-assets.php >/dev/null 2>&1

Comment: I get this error occasionally, too. And it happens for cron jobs that work 99% of the time. This tells me it's not a problem with the cron command itself but rather with the cron program.

Comment: I'm having this issue, too, I'm going to ask bluehost about it.